# gRPC with dynamic messages as an argument

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

After reading that protobuf supports creation of dynamic messages on the fly, I am trying to create a gRPC service that returns a dynamic message. (e.g. a service that returns a row in database but the schema is only known at run time)

Is it possible and how would I construct the .proto for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java there is a special object called [DynamicMessage](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/java/core/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/DynamicMessage.java) which can take a descriptor and send that.  If you can get the descriptor at runtime you can get it that way.

Also, while not exactly in the spirit of proto, you can represent arbitrary structured data using [struct.proto](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/struct.proto).