# grpc-java define service and methods without proto file

Tags: grpc, grpc-java, grpc-go

In my grpc application, I need to have a service that has just two client-side streaming methods. Is it possible to define the service, messages without creating a .proto file in grpc-java?. If yes, can you point me to an example or tutorial.

Comment: Yes, probably! I'm most familiar with Golang which has `types/dynamicpb` but this answer (DynamicMessage) may help get you going: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37690755/609290

Comment: Are you wanting to use protocol buffers, just not create a .proto, or are you wanting to use some other form of message?

Comment: @EricAnderson Yes, Can we use gRPC with JSON. Or Can we have gRPC service which expose both protobuf and JSON and response on basis of Content-Type?

Comment: @dReAmEr As you mentioned "Or Can we have gRPC service which expose both protobuf and JSON and response on basis of Content-Type". How to achieve the same in Java.